# PHP down after installing gb library on ubuntu/nginx

Tags: php, ubuntu, nginx, gd

I ran the `apt-get install php5-gd` command and now none of my sites in the box will load. I'm seeing a 502 Bad Gateway nginx/1.1.19.

I've tried adding two lines to Nginx configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf but still won't load:

```
http {
    ...
    fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    ...
}
```

Error log:

```
[31-Jul-2014 05:39:42] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[31-Jul-2014 05:39:42] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[31-Jul-2014 05:40:15] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful

[31-Jul-2014 05:40:15] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 8808
[31-Jul-2014 05:40:15] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[31-Jul-2014 05:44:11] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[31-Jul-2014 05:44:11] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[31-Jul-2014 05:44:11] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 8933
[31-Jul-2014 05:44:11] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[31-Jul-2014 05:49:43] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[31-Jul-2014 05:49:43] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[31-Jul-2014 05:49:43] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 8976
[31-Jul-2014 05:49:43] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[31-Jul-2014 05:52:38] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[31-Jul-2014 05:52:38] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[31-Jul-2014 05:52:38] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 9013
[31-Jul-2014 05:52:38] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[31-Jul-2014 06:03:00] NOTICE: configuration file /etc/php5/fpm/php-fpm.conf test is successful

[31-Jul-2014 06:09:58] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[31-Jul-2014 06:09:58] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[31-Jul-2014 06:10:00] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 9156
[31-Jul-2014 06:10:00] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
[31-Jul-2014 06:10:37] WARNING: [pool www] server reached max_children setting (10), consider raising it
[31-Jul-2014 06:11:52] NOTICE: Finishing ...
[31-Jul-2014 06:11:52] NOTICE: exiting, bye-bye!
[31-Jul-2014 06:11:57] ALERT: [pool www] user has not been defined
[31-Jul-2014 06:11:57] ERROR: failed to post process the configuration
[31-Jul-2014 06:11:57] ERROR: FPM initialization failed
[31-Jul-2014 06:12:32] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 9217
[31-Jul-2014 06:12:32] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
```

Comment: Try checking your error log.

Comment: All sorted, never mind :) thank you!